# Accessing dataframes via lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I was trying to change my dataframes, which are in a list `dfList = [df1, df2, df3]` by accessing them through list references: `dfList[0] = pd.dataFrame("bigChange")`

Unfortunately this does not actually change my dataframes. I cannot really find anything regarding this online, does anybody know why it is not possible?

Comment: You aren't changing the data frames. You are replacing teh dataframe at index `0` with a new dataframe.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a new dataframe instead of changing your old one.

If you have

```
import pandas as pd
...
dfList = [df1, df2, df3]
```

and now you

```
dfList[0] = pd.dataFrame("bigChange")
```

`df[0]`  is not `df1`, rather it is `pd.dataFrame("bigChange")`

So if you want to modify/change `df1` at `df[0]` then you must access it first and modfiy it not replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have a list with 3 dataframes created as below:

```
import pandas as pd
# initialize list elements
data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Numbers'])

dfList = [df, df, df]
```

You can update the new dataframe in the list by doing:

```
new_data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
dfList[0] = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['Numbers'])
print(dfList)
```

Comment: This is not quite my question but it was answered above already in the comments. Thank you anyways!